# Regex in vim editor

Tags: regex, shell, vim

I got so many lines in my file like this

```
xid: SC2152 id: artf24841
```

That i want to change it to like this

```
SC2152,artf24841
```

Kindly help

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to remove the `xid:` prefix, and replace the `id:` one with a comma. You can do this two ways:

#### First remove, then replace

```
:%s/xid: //
:%s/ id: /,/
```

#### Capture and reassemble

```
:%s/xid: \(.*\) id: \(.*\)/\1,\2/
```

This uses *capture groups* to select the parts of the line you want to keep (`\(...\)`). In the replacement part, the group content is inserted via `\1` and `\2`. Anything matched but not captured is lost; the new comma separator is put in the replacement.

---

This all is very basic stuff, and worthwhile to master. Read `:help :substitute`, or follow one of the several vi / Vim tutorials on the web.

Comment: Thanks ingo, As you said am new to regex any way i have tried this :%s/\(\w+\): (\w+\) id: (\w+\)/2,3/gi before posting but ur stuff works thanks now i have understand how to do this thanks again

Comment: Thanks; glad I could help. Your attempt was quite close already. Learn how the excellent and comprehensive `:help` is structured; all the information is in there (you just need to know how to find it)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this substitute command:

```
:s/ id: /,/
```